# c# iterating SPWeb.Navigation.GlobalNodes

Tags: development, navigation, spweb, spnavigationnode

When I try to iterate through the GlobalNodes collection using c# it is always empty unless I the site and manipulate the navigation settings manually.

Can anyone tell me why this is and/or give an alternative?

```
using (var site = new SPSite(url))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb)
    {
        // this is blank
        var nodes = web.Navigation.GlobalNodes[0].Children;
        //do things...
    }
}
```

If I then go to the site/_layouts/settings.aspx > Look and Feel > navigation and move a site around a bit in the navigation settings the list then shows up when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.globalnodes) GlobalNodes contains "the top-level navigation nodes for the current context" which includes Home, QuickLaunch and TopNavigationBar. That suggests that the code you listed is empty because the 0th index (possibly Home) is empty.

What navigation nodes are you trying to access? Perhaps it would be better to use the Home QuickLaunch or TopNavigationBar members of web.Navigation directly?

Comment: TopNavigationBar is also empty until you make a change to the default navigation properties (changing the order is enough to fill the node collections)

Comment: Looking at the API a bit more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg277254.aspx "If UseShared returns false, the website has its own top link bar and you can add to it. If the property returns true, the website is using its parent site's top link bar." by modifying it I guess it sets useShared to false.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. The UseShared property and your guess sounds feasible though.

Comment: +1 though for helping me find a solution though.